Rust crate opencv gives error core::hfloat not found
I'm trying to do object recognition in Rust with a YOLOv7 model. These are the dependencies:
[dependencies]
od_opencv = "0.1.5"
opencv = "0.88.9"

At first I tried to show my camera and as always it worked, but then I found an issue. I tried upgrading opencv installed in my computer, but then the error came up:
Compiling opencv v0.88.9
error[E0412]: cannot find type `hfloat` in module `core`
    --> /home/alebridi/Scrivania/programmazione/Rust/object_detection/target/debug/build/opencv-fa380b20c0f70dd9/out/opencv/core.rs:1892:29
     |
1892 |     pub type float16_t = core::hfloat;
     |                                ^^^^^^ not found in `core`

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0412`.
error: could not compile `opencv` (lib) due to 1 previous error

I tried reinstalling from source opencv, but it didn't work. Tried using the last version of the library (0.89.0), but the error is the same. I don't know what else I can do.
